# Git Push to Deploy stopped 'deploy source only' on all App Engine projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Since yesterday evening the Push-to-Deploy stopped working totally. If I Push a Git commit to the master it's not been deployed anymore. At first I thought this was a problem related to the App Engine Project itself. I've deleted the Release Pipeline and wanted to recreate it. Now the Console only shows the instructions to create a Jenkins Pipeline.

> See this documentation for information on how to set up Jenkins, and configure continuous deployment for your GCP apps.

After that I've manually deployed the app to see if there are any issues with my source. The GoogleAppEngineLauncher is deploying the application with no problem at all. I've tried to reproduce this in other AE projects and noticed **all projects** currently don't process the Git pushes into a deployment.

Are more users experiencing this?

Comment: As I said earlier, I didn't try pushing-and-deploying existing projects yet but for new projects I just can't find a way to create a "normal" pipeline anymore. I sincerely hope they didn't remove that.

Comment: I also experienced this behaviour a couple of hours ago. Now push-to-deploy is working again.

Comment: It's working again on existing projects but the Releases dashboard still displays an error: `Failed to load history information.`

Also I'm unable to create a new Release Pipeline for new projects or projects which didn't have a Release Pipeline yet.

Comment: I found the email Google sent out to us in December. It states that this feature is going down. I kind of just forgot that, but didn't expect it to stop working for existing projects. If that works, all is "well"? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868703/129202

Comment: This is really a shame. I haven't received this message.

Answer (score 3):

Yea, Now you have to use Jenkins using google cloud instance. See the updated documentation on there website https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy

Comment: Even that link is dead now. What is the latest way to do this?

Comment: @captncraig [that link](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) does work as of today? But it does look quite a bit different from this archived link as of [Sept. 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905235722/https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy)

Comment: Yeah, it just goes to the documentation home, not any relevant page.