# Push to deploy, pipelines, google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, continuous-deployment

Where did GAE push-to-deploy pipelines go?
I see all the new stuff with Jenkins and all, but is the good old pipeline setup gone? It took like 10 seconds to setup and worked really well recently. I still use it for ~5 ongoing production environments. I am in need of using it for the next project, but I can't find it.

If all else fails, do we have to use Jenkins? It might not be a problem in the end, however I would question the need to be billed for act of *deploying* own source code. Anyway it would be a mess to setup at first.

Comment: I've posted this same question about an hour ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827270/git-push-to-deploy-stopped-deploy-source-only-on-all-app-engine-projects

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I didn't know existing pipelines don't work though. That sounds alarming.

Answer (score 5):

I did get this email, and now stumbled upon it... I think it states what's going on.

> Hello,
>
> The ability to quickly, easily and safely deploy your code is an
>   important part of a great cloud developer experience. You have used
>   the Release Pipelines feature on GCP to push-to-deploy and have given
>   us very insightful feedback. We heard clearly that you want more
>   flexibility and control. So we have decided to move the product in
>   this direction.
>
> Instead of a pipeline with a small number of options, we want to offer
>   you the full flexibility of Jenkins. We heard that setting up Jenkins
>   is hard, so we are giving you tools to make that simpler. There are
>   instructions explaining how to set up Jenkins and configure continuous
>   deployment for your GCP apps, using provided plugins.
>
> With the availability of this solution, we are going to remove the
>   Release Pipelines UI in the Developer Console by January 22. If you
>   are currently using the build/test options, please remember to disable
>   your pipeline so you are no longer charged for it.
>
> Note that repo sync with GitHub and Bitbucket is still supported and
>   the Jenkins plugin to trigger a deployment from the push event is
>   included above.
>
> If you used the 'source only' option in Release Pipelines, going
>   forward you can use gcloud app update to deploy source to App Engine.
>
> If you have any questions, please email
>   release-pipelines-support@googlegroups.com.
>
> Google Cloud Release Pipelines team

Links disappeared when pasting the email so the last link to the docs is: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app

<s>I think I should be able to continue deploying source for rexisting projects using `gcloud app update`... I have yet to try though.</s>

This thread is also related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/XUIh7QlO37U
It specifically states that existing projects should continue to be able to deploy as we used to be able to. New projects would likely have to use Jenkins... hm.

There is no command like <s>`gcloud app update`</s>. Instead we have to cd into the project folder where the app.yaml is and run:

`gcloud preview app deploy .`

But FIRST(!) we have to install something more (if the above command fails):

`gcloud components update app`

Of course, this means that there is no "push", only a "deploy". There will be no relation to a central repository at Google. You have to host your own repo for that... in essence, this is not much different than deploying using the desktop GoogleAppEngineLauncher to me.